# Сравнить 2 массива

Tags: javascript

Arr1

```
[{
  "id": 1, "name": "iphone", "checked": false
},{
  "id": 2, "name": "samsung", "checked": false
},{ 
  "id": 3, "name": "huawei", "checked": false
}]
```

Arr2

```
[{
  "id": 15, "name": "iphone", "checked": true
},{
  "id": 16, "name": "samsung", "checked": true
}]
```

Результат

```
[{
  "id": 15, "name": "iphone", "checked": true
},{
  "id": 16, "name": "samsung", "checked": true
},{
  "id": 3, "name": "huawei", "checked": false
}]
```

Если name одинаковое то записать в массив значение где checked: true.

Моё решение

```
 this.Arr1.forEach((element) => {
        if(!~this.Arr2.indexOf(element)){
          this.Arr2.push(element);
          console.log(this.Arr2);
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
'use strict';

const arr1 = [
  {
    "id": 1, "name": "iphone", "checked": false
  }, {
    "id": 2, "name": "samsung", "checked": false
  }, {
    "id": 3, "name": "huawei", "checked": false
  },
];


const arr2 = [
  {
    "id": 15, "name": "iphone", "checked": true
  }, {
    "id": 16, "name": "samsung", "checked": true
  },
];

arr1.forEach((element1, index) => {
  const newElement = arr2.find(
    element2 => element1.name === element2.name && element2.checked === true
  );

  if (newElement) arr1[index] = newElement;
});

console.log(arr1);
```

Comment: можешь подсказать по этому посту https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1142707/%d0%a1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0

Comment: Попробовал ответить.

Answer (score 1):

Универсальная функция, принимающая на вход разное количество массивов, и которая не изменяет входящие массивы:

```
function combine (arrays = []) {
  let result = []
  arrays.forEach(array => {
    array.forEach(item => {
      let coincidence = result.find(i => i.name === item.name)
      if (!coincidence) {
        result.push(item)
      } else if (item.checked === true) {
        result = result.map(i => i.name === item.name ? item : i)
      }
    })
  })
  return result
}

const res = combine([array1, array2])
console.log('res', res)
```