# Сравнить два массива

Tags: javascript

Как сравнить 2 массива при этом arr1 сортировался по position 1 , 2 и тд, arr2 добавить в конец arr1

arr2

```
  [{
    "id": 1, "name": "iphone", position: 0, "checked": false
  },{
    "id": 2, "name": "samsung", position: 0, "checked": false
  },{ 
    "id": 3, "name": "huawei", position: 0, "checked": false
  }]
```

arr1

```
 [{
   "id": 16, "name": "samsung", position: 2, "checked": true
 },{
   "id": 15, "name": "iphone", position: 1, "checked": true
 }]
```

Результат

```
 [{
      "id": 15, "name": "iphone", position: 1, "checked": true
 },{
      "id": 16, "name": "samsung", position: 2, "checked": true
 },{
      "id": 1, "name": "iphone", position: 0, "checked": false
 },{
      "id": 2, "name": "samsung", position: 0, "checked": false
 },{ 
      "id": 3, "name": "huawei", position: 0, "checked": false
 }]
```

Comment: [Array.prototype.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

Comment: в моем решений как это будет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понимаю, что в данном случае подразумевается под сравнением. Если нужно соединить два массива объектов, а первый при этом отсортировать по полю `position`, можно так (имейте в виду, что первый массив останется отсортированным — если это нежелательно, можно создать его копию перед сортировкой):

```js
const arr1 = [
  { "id": 16, "name": "samsung", position: 2, "checked": true },
  { "id": 15, "name": "iphone", position: 1, "checked": true },
];

const arr2 =[
  { "id": 1, "name": "iphone", position: 0, "checked": false },
  { "id": 2, "name": "samsung", position: 0, "checked": false },
  { "id": 3, "name": "huawei", position: 0, "checked": false },
];

const result = arr1.sort((a, b) => a.position - b.position).concat(arr2);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

ES6

```
const arr1 = [1,2,3]
const arr2 = [4,5,6]
const arr3 = [...arr1, ...arr2] //arr3 ==> [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Ну или
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat